"Seems like he really had a brother!" Why is this utterance put in the past tense?

A: This is Takeshi's brother.
B: So wonderful to finally meet you! Seems like Takeshi really had a brother after all! (YouTube)

I find the use of past tense a little confusing. The bother is introduced and is right there with everybody else. So the situation is that Takeshi has a brother rather than that he had one but lost him. The simple present would make much more sense to me in this context. "We thought he didn't have a brother, but turns out he does have one."
For what it's worth, this snippet is from a Japanese drama set in the U.S.. While some of the actors seem to be native English speakers the script could have been written by Japanese screenwriters. In Japanese it's idiomatic to use the past tense in situations where the speaker finds something, makes a discovery of something or has a eureka moment, but I'm not sure it's equally idiomatic in English.
Similarly I also encountered this dialog in a work of fiction

Marshall said, "This guy here isn't with them. He helped them this far, but evidently he isn't going their way. Seems like he really had something else to do, in a different direction." (source)

"This guy" can't offer two ladies a ride because he is not going their way. "He has something else to do in a different direction" would make more sense to me.

"We thought he didn't have a brother, but turns out he does have one." That is exactly what it means, in English as well as Japanese. She goes on to say "We thought he was an orphan" (presumably meaning 'he was alone in the world' rather then 'his parents were dead').

The example about having a brother is a bit weird because you can't ordinarily tell if a person has a brother by looking at them or other methods. So you're not normally surprised to find out someone does or doesn't have a brother. If someone seems really unlovable but you see him making out with a girl, you might say (surprisedly) "He has a girlfriend!" But if you thought he was lying in the past when he said he had a girlfriend you might say "He had a girlfriend!" or "He did have a girlfriend!"

The context is that in the past there was uncertainty and discussion about Takeshi' brother.  Probably Takeshi claimed to have a brother but the speaker didn't believe him.
So the speaker is saying "I was wrong, and when I doubted Takeshi, he had a brother."
Of course Takeshi's brother is still alive, so the speaker could have used the present tense too.  In natural situations, The choice of "past" tense is probably an unconscious one since he is thinking about his past doubts.  In this case it might be influence by the the tense in the original.
(The choice of tense is natural enough,  but it seems a very odd thing to say to someone when you first meet them)
